# Open Additional Device Properties via Commandline

Tags: command-line, rundll32.exe, shell32.dll

In Windows 10 under Settings > System > Sound > Device Properties there is a link to a related setting  called "**Additional device properties**", where you have the Tabs General/Listen/Levels/Advanced.

I would like to directly display the advanced device properties for a given DeviceID. Any ideas how to execute it via commandline?

All I found so far is this command, which displays the properties of the device manager, but that's just quite not what I want. Since the settings is reachable from the Sound settings, I assume it has somehow to be related to mmsys.cpl?

```
rundll32.exe devmgr.dll,DeviceProperties_RunDLL /DeviceID XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I traced the dialog window, and its invocation is by the command:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe" C:\WINDOWS\System32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL C:\WINDOWS\System32\mmsys.cpl ms-mmsys:,{0.0.0.00000000}.{71313e65-fd54-4bcd-ba60-916aa5af22f4},general
```

I got to this dialog via
*Settings > System > Sound > Device properties >
Additional device properties*.

Comment: Phenomenal! Can you please give me some insights on how you traced it? I'm sure this could be used for various other situations as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I used Process Explorer to find the process by dragging the bullseye over the dialog.

Comment: @harrymc it is weird that it only works correctly via the win10 settings and not the classic control panel access method (Control Panel > Sound > Choose "Speakers" > Prperties) It is the same window, yet procexp won't trace the path to that window, only the "sounds" module. Example, if done with "old" control panel, you get `"C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe" C:\WINDOWS\System32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL C:\WINDOWS\System32\mmsys.cpl` instead and not the full invocation command. Just thought it was interesting.

Comment: You should select the sound device - "speakers" does not pertain to the device. My answer is about the properties of the sound device.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a BAT file for myself to launch "Enhancements" tab for one of my audio playback devices.

```
start /b C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe 
shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,
{0.0.0.00000000}.{886ebd94-fdbc-4ea4-9702-5277a00f3100},2
```

The UUID of the output can be found in device settings (pic). It's just one of the Children.

[image: 3 steps to the the UUID]

Interesting fact: Few days ago my UUID changed and I had to find it again. I am very tempted to write a small AHK script now :)